# Open Stripe checkout in new tab instead of redirecting to checkout

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I tried to open stripe checkout in a new tab instead of redirecting in the same tab.
The documentation doesn't seem to show any parameter to specify this wanted behavior.
https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout

I would like something like target="_blank"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it is currently not supported but there is a `feasible` solution mentioned by the guy who opened the issue.
see: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/700#issuecomment-535588300

Comment: "open a new tab and then run stripe's redirect function from there"